# Differential equation - delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation please?

$-y''+2ay'+(b^2-a^2)y=\delta$

I found charakteristic roots $\lambda_{1,2} = a \pm \sqrt{a^2+(b^2-a^2)}$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The solution has the form $y=y_0u$ where $u$ is the step function, $y_0$ a homogeneous solution with $y_0(0)=0$ and $y_0'(0)=-1$.

Also, you should simplify your expressions, $λ_{1,2}=a±b$.

Thus the solution for $y_0$ is $y_0(t)=Ce^{ax}\sinh(bx)$ with 
$$y_0'(x)=Ce^{ax}(a\sinh(bx)+b\cosh(bx))\implies Cb=-1, ~~C=-\frac1b.$$
So that
$$
y(x)=-\frac{e^{ax}\sinh(bx)}b u(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you, so I have $y^+ = c_1^+e^{-(a+b)x}+c_2^+e^{-(a-b)x}$ for x > 0 and $y^- = c_1^-e^{-(a+b)x}+c_2^-e^{-(a-b)x}$ . What will be please the conditions of sticking?

Comment: Usually, if no further information is given, the implicit condition for this type of problem is that $y(t)=0$ for $t<0$, conforming to the use of the Laplace transform for the solution. Thus $c_{1,2}^-=0$.

Comment: @Elisabeth : Check again the sign in the exponential factors.

Comment: There should be + in the arguments of first exponentials functions. How to do Laplace transform in this equation? I can't find any solved example

Comment: You look up a Laplace table like http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx and apply term-by-term, $Y={\cal L}[y]$ has the equation $$-(s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0))+2a(sY(s)-y(0))+(b^2-a^2)Y(s)=1,$$ then isolate $$Y(s)=-\frac{1+2ay(0)-y'(0)-sy(0)}{(s-a)^2-b^2}$$ and then perform a partial fraction decomposition or if possible look up the terms for the inverse Laplace transform by reading the table backwards.

Comment: Thank you. Thus I should use 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTkcs.png ? The result should be $y = \frac{1}{2b}e^{ax}e^{-b|x|}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87913/discussion-between-elisabeth-and-lutzl).

Comment: Yes, that is another solution with a simple form. Which one was required depends on the demanded initial condition or behavior at negative times.